# OverflowError python large calculation (division)

Tags: python, overflow, division

I'm trying to write a program to find odd Catalan numbers through Python but apparently Python can't divide really large numbers. 
Anybody knows how I can get around this? 
Here's my code:

```
# catalan number python program

import math

f = math.factorial

def ncr(n,r):
    return f(n)//(f(r)*f(n-r))


def catalan(x):
    return (ncr(2*x,x)/(x+1))


for i in range(1,600):
    z = catalan(i)
    if not z%2 == 0:
        print(str(i) + ' : ' + str(z))
```

I'm trying to get to at least the first 10,000 Catalan numbers, but my code currently can't even handle 1000. I don't need to print out the big number. I just want to know what number is it in.

Edit: add import math (whoops) and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/catalan odd tester.py", line 18, in <module>
    z = catalan(i)
  File "C:/Python34/catalan odd tester.py", line 14, in catalan
    return (ncr(2*x,x)/(x+1))
OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float
```

Comment: what line is it crashing on? ...try using some prints and try/except blocks to try and get a little more information .... you also might benifit from memoizing the ncr method

Comment: Why are you using floats?  (hint: replace / with //)

Comment: it is when i = 520 when the program crashes. catalan(519) = 1.4023904365091493e+308

Comment: it worked fine for me up to 10,000 using this exact code with python2.6 win32

Comment: Oh right.  '//' works. Welp, that was dumb of me. Thanks Patrick.

Comment: Yeah. I totally forgot that Python 3 do '/' division in float.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint. The code can find the catalan numbers. You just need to add statement to find the odd numbers now

```
def catalan(n):
    res = 0
    if( n <= 1):
        return 1
    for i in range(n):
        res += catalan(i) * catalan(n-i-1)
    return res
def main():
    for i in range(1000):
        print(catalan(i))
    return 0
main()
```